# Does smiles all over mean smiles are ended?

Tags: meaning

It is silly but I got confused over does it mean smiles are ended or does it mean smiles are everywhere?

Comment: Everywhere, in the sense of "all around" I guess. "All smiles *are* over" would mean there's no more smiles.

Comment: All over: 1. Over the whole area or extent: a cloth embroidered all over with roses.
2. Everywhere: searched all over for her missing key.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+over

Comment: "all over" here means "covering the entire surface". (As in "the car was painted red all over.")  It is a metaphor, meaning, "she was smiling a lot".

Comment: As a curiosity, "all over" (meaning, "covering the entire surface") is **not really used THAT MUCH** in English.  There's a famous riddle: "What's black and white and 'red' all over?" The answer is "a newspaper" - get it? ("red", "read")

Comment: @CopperKettle but smiles all around does not sounds weird?

Comment: Some context would be nice. It is hard to infer meaning without surrounding context in this case, as both could be correct.

Comment: At least 16 of the fist 50 citations in COCA (there are 1,534 in all) for *all over* have the expression meaning *everywhere*  (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/all-over) or 

*Over the whole area or extent*  (https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=all%20over), so it appears to be fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *Smiles all over* can also be expressed as *Smiles all around*. It is used to indicate that everyone is smiling.